# How to select records with not exists condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subquery, not-exists

I am have two dataframes as below. I want  to  rewrite the data selection SQL query into pandaswhich contains not exists condition

**SQL**

```
Select ORDER_NUM, DRIVER  FROM DF
                          WHERE
                          1=1
                        AND NOT EXISTS   
 (
        SELECT 1 FROM
                 order_addition oa
                 WHERE
                  oa.Flag_Value = 'Y'
            AND   df.ORDER_NUM  = oa.ORDER_NUM)
```

**Sample data**

```
order_addition.head(10)

ORDER_NUM   Flag_Value
22574536    Y
32459745    Y
15642314    Y
12478965    N
25845673    N
36789156    N

df.head(10)

ORDER_NUM   REGION  DRIVER
22574536    WEST    Ravi
32459745    WEST    David
15642314    SOUTH   Rahul
12478965    NORTH   David
25845673    SOUTH   Mani
36789156    SOUTH   Tim
```

How can this be done in pandas easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can `merge` on `df1` with values equal to Y, and then find the nans:

```
result = df2.merge(df1[df1["Flag_Value"].eq("Y")],how="left",on="ORDER_NUM")

print (result[result["Flag_Value"].isnull()])

   ORDER_NUM REGION DRIVER Flag_Value
3   12478965  NORTH  David        NaN
4   25845673  SOUTH   Mani        NaN
5   36789156  SOUTH    Tim        NaN
```

Or even simpler if your `ORDER_NUM` are unique:

```
print (df2.loc[~df2["ORDER_NUM"].isin(df1.loc[df1["Flag_Value"].eq("Y"),"ORDER_NUM"])])

   ORDER_NUM REGION DRIVER
3   12478965  NORTH  David
4   25845673  SOUTH   Mani
5   36789156  SOUTH    Tim
```

Comment: If I have more `and` condition in the subquery how can I include that as well into the above logic

Comment: You can chain your conditions like `df1[cond1&cond2&cond3...]`.

Comment: Where did you apply not exists condition

Comment: left join and find by `isnull()`. Is it your expected output?

Comment: If I had 'order number` from one more additional table in the inner query. How I could I do that

Comment: you can `concat` the two tables first.